# How to combine two Enumerators based on a key (Maintaining Iteratee state between Dones)?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.2, loops

I'm trying to combine two Play Framework Enumerators together but merging values that come through which have the same key value. For the most part it works, except, the Map used to keep previous values that do not have a match as of yet gets lost each time a match is found and a Done Iteratee is returned.

Is there a way to provide the state to the next invocation of step after a Done has been returned?

Any examples I've found thus far all seem to be around grouping consecutive values together and then passing the whole grouping along, and none on grouping some arbitrary values from the stream and only passing specific values along once grouped.

Ideally once the match is made it'll send the matched values along. 
What I've gotten to thus far, (pretty much based off of [Creating a time-based chunking Enumeratee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15311352/creating-a-time-based-chunking-enumeratee) )

```
def virtualSystemGrouping[E](system:ParentSystem): Iteratee[Detail, Detail] = {
  def step(state: Map[String, Detail])(input:Input[Detail]): Iteratee[Detail, Detail] = {
    input match {
      case Input.EOF => {Done(null, Input.EOF)}
      case Input.Empty =>{Cont[Detail, Detail](i => step(state)(i))}
      case Input.El(e) => {
        if (!system.isVirtual) Done(e)
        if (state.exists((k) =>{k._1.equals(e.name)})) {
          val other = state(e.name)
          // ??? should have a; state - e.name
          // And pass new state and merged value out.
          Done(e + other)
        } else {
          Cont[Detail, Detail](i => step(state + (e.name -> e))(i))
        }
      }
    }
  }
  Cont(step(Map[String,Detail]()))
}
```

The calling of this looks like;

```
   val systems:List[ParentSystem] = getSystems()
   val start = Enumerator.empty[Detail]
   val send = systems.foldLeft(start){(b,p) =>
     b interleave Concurrent.unicast[Detail]{channel =>
       implicit val timeout = Timeout (1 seconds)
       val actor = SystemsActor.lookupActor(p.name + "/details")
       actor map {
         case Some(a) => {a ! SendDetailInformation(channel)}
         case None => {channel.eofAndEnd}
         } recover {
         case t:Throwable => {channel.eofAndEnd}
       }

       }
   } &> Enumeratee.grouped(virtualSystemGrouping(parent)) |>> Iteratee.foreach(e => {output.push(e)})
   send.onComplete(t => output.eofAndEnd)
```

Comment: So far my guess on how to tackle this would be to do something like the Concurrent.joined def, where I create an Iteratee and an Enumerator, https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/iteratees/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/iteratee/Concurrent.scala#L797

Answer (score 0):

The one method that I've been able to come up with that works, is to use a Concurrent.unicast and pass the channel into the combining function. I'm sure there is a way to create an Iteratee/Enumerator that does the work all in one nice neat package, but that is eluding me at the time being.

Updated combining function;

```
def virtualSystemGrouping[E](system:ParentSystem, output:Channel): Iteratee[Detail, Detail] = {
  def step(state: Map[String, Detail])(input:Input[Detail]): Iteratee[Detail, Detail] = {
    input match {
      case Input.EOF => {
          state.mapValues(r=>output.push(r))
          output.eofAndEnd
          Done(null, Input.EOF)
      }
      case Input.Empty =>{Cont[Detail, Detail](i => step(state)(i))}
      case Input.El(e) => {
        if (!system.isVirtual) {output.push(e); Done(e, Input.Empty)}
        if (state.exists((k) =>{k._1.equals(e.name)})) {
          val other = state(e.name)
          output.push(e + other)
          Cont[Detail, Detail](i => step(state - e.name)(i))
        } else {
          Cont[Detail, Detail](i => step(state + (e.name -> e))(i))
        }
      }
    }
  }
  Cont(step(Map[String,Detail]()))
}
```

Here any combined values are pushed into the output channel and then subsequently processed.

The usage of this looks like the following;

```
   val systems:List[ParentSystem] = getSystems(parent)
   val start = Enumerator.empty[Detail]
   val concatDetail = systems.foldLeft(start){(b,p) =>
     b interleave Concurrent.unicast[Detail]{channel =>
       implicit val timeout = Timeout (1 seconds)
       val actor = SystemsActor.lookupActor(p.name + "/details")
       actor map {
         case Some(a) => {a ! SendRateInformation(channel)}
         case None => {channel.eofAndEnd}
         } recover {
         case t:Throwable => {channel.eofAndEnd}
       }

       }
   } 


   val combinedDetail = Concurrent.unicast[Detail]{channel => 
    concatDetail &> Enumeratee.grouped(virtualSystemGrouping(parent, channel)) |>> Iteratee.ignore
   }
   val send = combinedDetail |>> Iteratee.foreach(e => {output.push(e)})
   send.onComplete(t => output.eofAndEnd)
```

Very similar to the original except now the calling to the combining function is done within the unicast onStart block (where channel is defined). concatDetail is the Enumerator created from the interleaved results of the child systems.  This is fed through the system grouping function which in turn pushes any combined results (and remaining results at EOF) through the provided channel.

The combinedDetails Enumerator is then taken in and pushed through to the upstream output channel.

EDIT:
The virtualSystemGrouping can be generalized as;

```
  def enumGroup[E >: Null, K, M](
      key:(E) => K,
      merge:(E, Option[E]) => M,
      output:Concurrent.Channel[M]
      ): Iteratee[E, E] = {
    def step(state: Map[K, E])(input:Input[E]): Iteratee[E, E] = {
      input match {
        case Input.EOF => {
          state.mapValues(f => output.push(merge(f, None))) //Push along any remaining values.
          output.eofAndEnd();
          Done(null, Input.EOF)
          }
        case Input.Empty =>{ Cont[E, E](i => step(state)(i))}
        case Input.El(e) => {
          if (state.contains(key(e))) {
            output.push(merge(e, state.get(key(e))))
            Cont[E, E](i => step(state - key(e))(i))
          } else {
            Cont[E, E](i => step(state + (key(e) -> e))(i))
          }
        }
      }
    }

    Cont(step(Map[K,E]()))
  }
```

With a call such as;

```
Enumeratee.grouped(
             enumGroup(
             (k=>k.name),
             ((e1, e2) => e2.fold(e1)(v => e1 + v)),
             channel)
            )
```